# configurable timer

Tags: timer

I'm trying to build a security system that is configurable via a config file, perhaps XML.  One of the configurable options is hours of the day/night when the system should be recording.  There will be an entry or more for each day of the week.  I'm trying to implement this in python which is not a language I know well.  My main problem is how to implement this cleanly.  Basically the program will look something like this:

```
def check_if_on():
   """
   check if the system should be on based on current time and config file
   returns True iff system should be on, False otherwise
   """
   ...

# main loop
while True:
    # do something
    # do something else
    if check_if_on():
       # do something
    else:
       # do something else or nothing
    time.sleep(10)
```

the config file will look  something like:

```
<on-times>
  <on day="1" time="1900"/>
  <off day="2" time="0700"/>
  <on day="2" time="1800"/>
  <off day="3" time="0900"/>
</on-times>
```

A friend with a lot more experience than me said to implement the on/off times as timed events in a queue but I'm not sure if that's a good idea or even how to do it

Answer (score 0):

If super precise timing is not necessary, you could run it every minute as a cron job to save some CPU cycles. If time exceeded the configured time, do something, else do nothing.

Comment: thnx and sorry if I didn't make things clear.  There is no need to run cron as the program will run all the time and will be doing other things (hence the while True loop).  My question is how to best implement the logic of checking if the recording should be turned on or off based on the config file.  I can probably do it using some messy if else mess and am wondering if there is a better solution.  eg. my friend's suggestion: queue of timed events